# Error while converting binary to integer when the last bit is zero [low]

Tags: python

I am using manual method to convert binary to decimal. This code works fine where the last bit is high for eg: 1001. The error arises when the last bit is zero[low]. For eg: 1010 should give 10 but gives 5 because the last bit is not considered.Could any one help me in this.

```
x=raw_input('Enter the binary value:')
x=[int(xi) for xi in x]

sum=0
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    sum=sum+x[i]*(pow(2,i))

print sum
```

Comment: first of all sum is a builtin function name

Comment: You're doing the bits in reverse order i.e., you are treating the 'left-most' (first entered) bit as the least significant bit. So if you enter '1010', this is the binary number `0101` or decimal 5. Reverse the list `x` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Blair .You are absolutely right. The value x should be reversed as    x=x[::-1]. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're misinterpreting the problem. The issue isn't that it's ignoring the last bit if it's 0, the problem is that it's reading the binary sequence backwards. When you feed in "1010", it processes it as "0101".

```
sum = sum + x[i] * (pow(2, len(x) - i - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
x = raw_input('Enter the binary value:')
x = [int(i) for i in x]

s = sum(2**i for i,j in enumerate(x[::-1]) if j==1)

print(s)
```

This code reverses the input so that when we parse it bit by bit (pun intended), it raises 2 to the index of that bit if that bit is a 1. Also, do not use `sum` as a variable name. It is a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way to look at it would be:

```
x = '1010'

_sum = 0
for i in x: # go over every digit from left to right
    _sum = (_sum + int(i)) * 2
_sum /= 2  # when exiting the loop - we multiplied one extra time - fix it!

print _sum # prints 10
```

Comment: dang ive never seen it done that way it took me a while to convince myself it was right ... im still not entirely sure but +1 ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley ha ha :) when you start from the left the sum that's accumulated gets multiplied by 2 again and again the same number of times as the string's length ;)

Comment: yeah it makes sense and i believe it ... i just dont know why I never learned that ... or maybe i did I dont have to manually translate this stuff so i forgot alot of it

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't remember if I learnt it either, I suspect that it's my disgust to iterating strings backward that brought me to it :D